# Can any one provide mathematical technique details about turf js?

Tags: geospatial, turfjs

Can you tell me how turf js perform operation?
Like, Point to Ploygon, we can use buffer for that.

```js
var point = turf.point([-90.548630, 14.616599]);
var buffered = turf.buffer(point, 500, {units: 'miles'});
```

So which mathematical technique they are using for that?
As well as for Points to Envelop or Convex hull or concave.

Is there any documentation for that?

Comment: Isn't that an open source library? You can just look at the code to see what it does.

Comment: Hei, Thanks for your answer, yes I know that. Sometimes it tough to find out the formula after looking on the code. 
Like, they mentioned that for DISTANCE, "This uses the Haversine formula to account for global curvature."
So it will help me to get a better understanding after looking on the Haversine formula.
Something like that, what they are using for the convex hull?

Answer (score 1):

If you are curious about how does it work, you can source the code:
Here you have the [git dependency](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-buffer/index.js).

Also, the [point feature](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-point-on-feature/index.js).